# How to add multiple field values to a category expression in a chart using ireport?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have a table which looks like the following

ID    Name    Year    Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May          [These are the column names]

1    abc     2012    2.5   3.2  2.5   2.3   6.2 [These are the values in the rows of my table]

2   abc     2011    3.9   6.2  7.5   6.5   6.8

I am trying to create a line chart where x axis is my column names i.e, Jan, Feb and so on and my Y axis should be its corresponding values. Series expression would be the year.

Could some one please help me in creating the category expression and value expression since I am unable to do so?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reformat your query output to be:

```
 ID     Name     Year     Month     Value
  1      abc     2012     Jan       2.5
  1      abc     2012     Feb       3.2
  ...
  2      abc     2011     May       6.8
```

Your month could also be yyyy-mm, which might help better organize your output. Then on the x-axis (category) use the month, and for the y-axis (value), use value.

Comment: Thanks Lisa. I will try this approach and see if I can get the desired output.